# Efficiently mutating large table using ifelse in R

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, dplyr

Say I have a large data frame for e.g.

```
Block Subject Stim  
 10   100      1
 11   100      2
 12   100      1
 ...
 24.  101      1
 25   101      3
 26   101      1
 27   101      3
 28   101      3
 29   101      3
```

For every subject, every stim appears in either 2 or 4 blocks.
My objective is to mutate a column that determines for each row whether this is the first half of the blocks that this stim appears for this Subject (so if a stim appears in 2 blocks then I'm checking if its first block, and if in 4 I'm checking if this is within the first two blocks).

So my desired output would be

```
  Block Subject Stim  BlockType 
     10   100      1       1
     11   100      2       1
     12   100      1       2     # already learned in block 10 
     ...
     24.  101      1       1   # block 10/12 dont count since its a different subject
     25   101      3       1
     26   101      1       2   # already learned in block 24 
     27   101      3       1    # in four total blocks so still in bottom half 
     28   101      3       2
     29   101      3       2
```

I know i can do this with a forloop for each row but thats incredibly slow. Any suggestions for how i can speed it up would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT thanks to suggestion I try

```
   df %>%
  group_by(Subject,Stim) %>%
  mutate(BlockType = rep(c(1,2), each = n()/2, length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup()  -> result
```

Most of the outputs are correct but then sometimes I get a strange mistake

```
Block Subject Stim BlockType 
 13   1        2          1
 13   1        3          1
 13   1        2          2
```

Where that third row should be Blocktype 1. Any idea what could be tripping it up?

Comment: A `Stim` in every `Subject` can either have 2 or 4 rows right? In these 3 rows `Stim = 2` has 2 rows hence the 1st row BlockType  = 1 and 3rd is BlockType = 2. This is same as first 3 rows of the original dataset that you shared and your desired output includes `BlockType` as 1, 1 and 2 for first 3 rows.

Comment: Sorry i don't think i was clear. A stim for every Subject can have many rows but within only 2 or 4 blocks. So within each block the stim will repeat many times but the number of blocks where it occurs is either 2 or 4.

Comment: What do you mean by where it occurs? How does it look when it does not occur?

Comment: For example say stim=1 appears for subject 100 in blocks 10 and 12. In block 10 there are many instances where stim=1 and so to in block 12 there are many instances where stim=1. But for all instances of stim 1 in block 10 BlockType should be 1 alnd for all instances of stim 1 in block 12 it should be 2. 

So there are many rows for each block with stim repeating itself many times. The key is that its the first distinct block or 2nd distinct block

Comment: Do you need `df %>% group_by(Subject, Stim) %>%mutate(BlockType = match(Block, unique(Block)))` ? I don't understand why you have only 1 and 2 `BlockType` for `Subject = 101` when all the block types are different for that `Subject`.

Comment: Do you need `df %>% mutate(BlockType = data.table::rowid(Subject, Stim))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `rep` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Subject, Stim) %>%
  mutate(BlockType = rep(1:2, each = n()/2, length.out = n())) %>%
  ungroup() -> result

result
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. For some reason- it classifies most correctly but then sometimes i get strange incorrect outputs

Comment: Formatting is not clear in comments so it is hard to understand. Can you edit your post to clarify?

Comment: thank you for your help/patience. I re edited the original post. Let me know if its clear.